# How Do I Enable Developer Mode on Chromium OS Build Running from a USB Stick?

Tags: google-chrome, usb, usb-flash-drive, chromium, bootable-media

I've been interested in Chromebooks and Chrome OS for a while. Upon learning about the existence of openly available PC-compatible builds of the OS via [ArnoldTheBat](http://arnoldthebat.co.uk/wordpress/chromium-os/), I'd figure I'd get a first-hand look before deciding to buy any new hardware.

Cue a few days later, and here I am typing this post from Chromium OS running from a 4GB USB flash drive. Now I want to take this experiment further and install Crouton (XFCE) to give my flash drive a dual purpose: (1.) as easy access to my Google apps/browser, (2.) as a fully-blown Linux-to-go.

I already know how to install Crouton. My main issue is **enabling Developer Mode in Chromium OS on what is still not a Chromebook**. From what I read, all Chromebooks have a unique way of enabling Developer Mode, but because what I'm doing isn't exactly supported by Google, there's still no documentation on how to go about this.

Has anyone who has used ArnoldTheBat's Chromium builds been able to figure this out yet? Any help would be greatly appreciated.